# No /dev/dri directory in Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: 20.04, docker, plex

I have a headless Intel NUC 11PAKi5 (with i5-1135G7 CPU and integrated Iris Xe Graphics + Quick Sync), running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.

I'm trying to enable hardware transcoding in a Docker Plex container - which requires the
**/dev/dri/** directory to be made available to the container - but the **/dev/dri/** directory does not exist.

I would appreciate any help to understand how to pass the iGPU drivers through for use by the Plex Docker container. Thanks in advance!

**Other info:**

I'm successfully able to use the HDMI port with a monitor.

`lshw -c video` shows:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:603c000000-603cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

`lspci -v` shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 3004
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 603c000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Capabilities: [320] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Answer (score 4):

I was encountering a similar issue in 22.04.03 server (the next LTS) attempting to run headless on a NUC like device (based on Alder Lake N95). The root cause for me was that the Kernel Version was not new enough to support Gen 11+ (Alder Lake being Gen 12) iGPU's.

Switching to [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) as recommended by the [Known Issues and Limitations FAQ for Jellyfin Hardware Acceleration](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/administration/hardware-acceleration/intel#known-issues-and-limitations) using the following command:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-22.04`

Resolved my issue and allowed these devices to appear under `/dev/dri`:

```
~$ ls -l /dev/dri
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root         80 Sep  6 20:14 by-path
crw-rw---- 1 root video  226,   0 Sep  6 20:14 card0
crw-rw---- 1 root render 226, 128 Sep  6 20:01 renderD128
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, and it was because I had set `nomodeset` in my grub config. Removing that fixed it, though now I can't use a monitor for debugging without editing the grub config on the fly at boot. See here for more info: https://askubuntu.com/a/1154067

Comment: This was the only response that resolved /dev/dri absence problem on my server equipped with an Asrock Rack motherboard and UHD 630 graphics.