# Wrong refresh rate, missing EDID, and screen tearing on 4K TV over HDMI

Tags: hdmi, xrandr, tearing, 4k-monitor

I'm trying to use a mini PC (a Trigkey G4 with an Intel N95 CPU) running Ubuntu 22.04 as a home-theater PC, connected to my Hisense U6G television via an HDMI 2.1 cable. It connects and is able to display at the full 3840x2160 resolution, but there's terrible screen tearing when playing video (in both VLC and Firefox, windowed and full-screen, KDE Plasma and Gnome). While trying to debug this, I noticed that xrandr was giving incomplete and incorrect information about the available modes:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3840 x 2160, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 3840 x 2160
default connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (0x522) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x521
    Timestamp:  19564
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  3840x2160 (0x522) 729.907MHz *current
        h: width  3840 start    0 end    0 total 3840 skew    0 clock 190.08KHz
        v: height 2160 start    0 end    0 total 2160           clock  88.00Hz
```

Note the 88.00 Hz clock, when this TV is only listed as capable of 60 Hz. It seems plausible to me that sending frames at the wrong rate could be the cause of the tearing. Also note the lack of EDID information—when I tried to run `get-edid`, it failed with `Couldn't find an accessible EDID on this computer.`

To rule out issues with the TV itself or the cable, I connected it to my old laptop (also running Ubuntu 22.04), which had no problem displaying video without tearing, and was able to read the EDID without issue. I tried copying the good EDID over and providing it to the kernel via the `drm.edid_firmware` command-line option, but that had no noticeable effect.

At this point, I've tried most of advice I can find online—making a `20-intel.conf` with `TearFree` set to true has no effect, nor does setting `i915.alpha_support` or `nomodeset` or `GRUB_GFXMODE`, and `xrandr` won't allow me to change modes.

What else can I try to get smooth video output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the kernel that ships with 22.04 does not have support for the integrated GPU on newer processors like the Intel N95. To solve this, I installed `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` as recommended in
https://askubuntu.com/a/1484943/1731290 and now everything works great. It even fixed another issue, that I wasn't sure was related, where HDMI audio output wasn't being detected.

Comment: You select which kernel stack is installed by default for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS at download time. There is media that defaults to HWE (Ubuntu Desktop), and media that defaults to GA (Ubuntu Server), and even media that defaults depending upgrade level (22.04 & 22.04.1 using GA, & 22.04.2 & later using HWE)... thus default kernel choice is a selection made by user at install time (*or more specifically download time!*)

Comment: FYI:  The different media choices is something really useful in QA... I have 20.04 media with 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 kernels installed, and for 22.04 media with 5.15, 5.19 & 6.2 - though post-install that media will either stay on the GA kernel stack or upgrade to latest HWE stack.. We select at install time my point (with these choices super useful in QA).  Well done for solving it though.

Comment: @guiverc Interesting. I don't recall seeing the option to choose a kernel version, either when I downloaded the ISO from Ubuntu's site or when I installed it, because I'm pretty sure I would have chosen the newest option if given a choice.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop (20.04 & *later*) default to HWE with no choice except by selecting the ISO (regardless of installer used; with 2 choices selected by ISO). Ubuntu Server defaults to the GA kernel stack, though some ISO/releases allow you to select during install (*live* will use GA, but after first boot you can have HWE installed) but default is GA (unless changed; and some ISOs don't allow choice; two installers available for older releases, only `subiquity` for later release). For *flavors* the 22.04 & 22.04.1 defaulted to GA though some could switch to OEM & 22.04.2 & later defaulted to HWE

Comment: Kernel stack is mentioned in many docs (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack along with many others, including Server docs) and not at the download page, only `subiquity` ISOs (5 installers have been available but some releases only have 3 installer choices selected by ISO; `ubiquity`, `subiquity` and `calamares` available for 22.04, though *canary* which is now known as `ubuntu-desktop-installer` was also available if you searched for it on ISO tracker). Kernel stack defaults have changed last decade+, last change was at 20.04 (*impacting Ubuntu Desktop*)

Comment: If you were looking for a clear indicator at download - nope it's not there.. It's *assumed* knowledge that was written about quite a bit when introduced (*a decade+ ago now though*). Server systems want the most *stable* thus GA is default; Desktop systems with GUI are generally better with newer thus HWE is default as newer video cards benefit from new kernels/kernel modules (aka *drivers*). As servers don't include GUI or graphic cards they won't benefit from newer software stack, and old stack has the longer track record for *stability*.